# Malicious Code Through Image Upload

Tags: php, validation, image-processing

There is a part of my website that allows users to upload profile photos. I'm worried about people uploading malicious code. I'm planning on limiting the the file types to .jpg/.png/.gif/.jpeg

I'm worried that it won't be enough. I'm going to be resize thing images on the server. Would the process of resizing the photos be enough to ensure that the image is actually an image not malicious files?

I'll be using the following to resize the photos. I won't be storing the originals on the server and the files names will be changed.

```
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($thumb, $fullpath, 90);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply doing this will ensure you're working on an image :

```
if (getimagesize($sourcePath) === false)
{
   die("Not an image !");
}
```

For more safety you should disable PHP execution in the upload folder.
In .htaccess:

```
php_value engine off
```

Comment: Maybe for someone new to PHP who finds this post, you should change `panic` to `die` in case they literally copy and paste this code!

Comment: I didn't even think about disabling php execution as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  I have found a link which discusses it here:

http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/67-PHP-security-exploit-with-GIF-images.html

From personal experience, I mostly only allow image upload behind a password shield so I 'know' my users, but I almost always do a resize as well - my gut feeling would be that that would be enough as it destroys the original file and replaces it with your own resampled version.

Answer (score -1):

This is a non-issue because I don't see how it could even happen.
However, I don't know aht your functions do (you didn't publish the source code).

As long as I know, it's not possible to inject PHP. You can inject SQL, Javascript, HTML, ...

Comment: Of course it is an issue! Even if you could not inject PHP (and you could, but the website must be coded really awfully for php injection to work in a file upload form).

Comment: You answered your question yourself: "I'm planning on limiting the file types to JPG, PNG, etc.". There is nothing more to do. As long as your webserver doesn't execute JPG files as PHP, there is no problem.